# Inequality constraints ambiguity in IOS Auto layout and Missing Constraints in Line

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

[image]

I just Created with Layout with Scroll view and several textfields.I just tried some constraints such as vertical spacing and horizontal spacing.BUt get some errors(Error screen is attached as image).Can u tell me what I miss